# Uploading and updating ubuntu repository with new deb

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg, deb

My problem is as follows:

I have an ubuntu package repository which I want to update with some packages.

I've been browsing around trying to figure out how this is done and came across '`dput`'. Unfortunately dput requires the existence of '.`chages`' which I don't have (I only have the `.deb-s` which I want to upload).

Is there any other way of uploading the deb and updating the package repository?

Also, does anybody know where I can find some decent documentation on working with *ubuntu/debian* repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have your **own** repository but you did not mention what software do you use to maintain it.

We use [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/) and there is a simple way how to add a standalone .deb package (without .changes):

copy the .deb to the repository server, wherever you have an access to, like /tmp and execute:

```
$ reprepro includedeb <codename> /tmp/<debfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be quite surprised if you indeed found a Debian repository that allowed write access for everybody. That said, the `*.changes` file is automatically created by the package build process. If you do not have it, you probably did not build the package yourself, did you?

Oh, and there is lots of documentation on Debian packages and repositories on (surprise) the [Debian developer web site](http://www.debian.org/devel/).